# Parsing a definition concerning trees and tuples

Tags: elementary-set-theory, trees, cantor-set

Definition: Let $T$ be a tree.  Given a set $X$, we define a $T-tuple$ of elements of $X$ to be a function

**x**: $T\rightarrow X$

Alternatively, we sometimes refer to a $T$-tuple as a *tree of elements in X*.  If **x** is a $T$-tuple, we often denote the value of **x** at t by $x_t$.  Also, the function **x** is denoted $(x_t)_{t\in T}.$

I am having trouble accessing the meaning of the above definition. How would the Cantor ternary construction be expressed using this language?

Comment: I don’t see any reason or good way to employ this language in connection with the Cantor ternary construction.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I suppose one might use this language to index the removed intervals by the nodes of a complete infinite binary tree. But I agree that this doesn't in itself seem to buy us anything particularly useful.

Comment: I thought if I could see how it applied to a simple interval tree, I might be able to generalize from there.

Comment: A "$T$-tuple of elements of $X$" is just a labelling of the vertices of the tree $T$ with elements of $X$. You can always label the vertices with themselves :) which In the case of the Cantor set seems to be the only natural thing to do. Each vertex is an interval $I$, beginning with the unit interval at level $0$, progressing to $[0, 1/3]$ and $[2/3,1]$ at level $1$, and so on. These intervals $I$ *are* the vertices of the tree, so let $x_I = I$. As @BrianM.Scott said, it doesn't really buy us anything.